# Possible notification in Browser tab

Tags: feature-request, notifications, tabs

I am just wondering if there is any talk about adding notifications to the tab (like gmail) on stack overflow. It would come in handy as at the moment comments, notifications etc only appear if the page is reloaded.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+title+notification+is%3Aquestion :)